# how do i figure out what my exact objective gradient and hessian for a scipy optimize problem?

Tags: python, scipy, gradient, scipy-optimize, hessian

Other answers have mentioned that providing the exact objective gradient and hessian will speed up the process as it doesn't have to use an approximation. If this is my objective function, how do I figure out the gradient and hessian?

```
def er(x,df=df):
   return -((x*df['pred']).sum())
```

isn't it just -df['pred'] and 0 since df['pred'] are just constants? x would be the variable I am trying to optimize.

Comment: Hint: your objective function is literally just a [scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) f(x) = - c^T * x, so the gradient is f'(x) = -c, where c is the vector containing your values (`df['pred']` in your case, assuming it's a one-dimensional numpy array)

Comment: @joni ok and then what about the h essian?

Comment: Well, I already gave you the gradient. You only need to differentiate the gradient wrt x in order to get the hessian matrix. *Mathematical* optimization requires at least basic calculus knowledge. Maybe it helps to consider a scalar problem like g(x) = 5*x first. The first derivative (gradient) is g'(x)=5. What's the second derivative aka the hessian matrix?

Comment: @joni ya its just zero but is it an array of zeros or just straight up zero? The reason I am asking such a dumb question is because when I make these changes, I get totally different (and unacceptably suboptimal) answers.